# Netbeans not responsing output & running any program create errors due to ant

Tags: netbeans-7.2

I am getting this problem after running any program in netbeans7.2

my java path are as follows

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin
```

my netbeans install in `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2 Beta`

The following error occurred while executing this line:

```
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.2%20Beta/java/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type componentdef
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Comment: you seem to be using beta? (see in output - NetBeans%207.2%20Beta) so maybe use a final version of 7.2 or even better, use 7.3.1. That's the latest final release.

Comment: can you provide me its solution in netbeans 7.2 rather than using newer version